# ¿Cómo explorar archivos para buscar base de datos por el usuario en Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

He visto aplicaciones donde le brindan al usuario la posibilidad de especificar la ubicación de una base de datos esté donde esté en el sistema (sea Memoria interna o Micro SD) a través de un pequeño explorer que te muestra todas las carpetas de tu télefono. Si alguien sabe el código para eso se lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿Para que quieres que el usuario eliga una base de datos? ¿Quieres hacer algo como importar o exportar datos?

Comment: Hay dispositivos que gestionan la memoria diferente.Ejemplo la base de datos mia hay que copiarla en la memoria interna que es un LG L90 pero en el de un compañero mio que tiene un huawei hay que copiarla en la Micro Sd para que la app lea la bd.Por eso es que estoy pidiendo un explorer para que el mismo user lo busque.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Abrir carpeta"));
```

Con esto tienes acceso al file manager por defecto del móvil. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Muy sencillo; para saber si la SD está disponible o no:

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(isSDPresent)
{
  // Tiene SD
}
else
{
 // No tiene SD / No es accesible
}
```